# Migrate MySql Database to sqlite for android

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse, sqlite

I want to convert mysql database to sqlite databse for android. I have mysql .sql db, i want to convert in sqlite & where is it store in eclipse??

Thanks
Nitin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of tools to help you with the migration: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

And probably there is some typo in the question. SQLite database is stored on device in the folder `/data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>`  In case you want to access it with adb, I recommend you go through run-as command too :)